Existing React Stack Snippets broken by update
The recent update to Stack Snippets breaks existing React snippets in posts. The Run code snippet button is there, but the snippet doesn't work anymore. (Related but different: Button to "Run code snippet" not appearing when question/answer is posted)
Example: This answer contains a Stack Snippet last edited in 2018. It used to work. Now it doesn't. The same thing happened to the snippets in this answer here on meta, but I fixed them manually.
If I edit that answer and just open the Snippet editor, that fixes it. Looking at what changes, it updates the begin snippet. Originally it was:
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: true -->

The editor changes it to:
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: true babelPresetReact: true babelPresetTS: false -->

It's great that it can easily be fixed manually, but there are hundreds of thousands of questions and answers using React in Stack Snippets[citation needed] and manually fixing Each And Every One Of Them is not an option.
Either the update needs to be made to work with these snippets as-is, or there needs to be a mass edit applied to fix the snippets that are now broken.

The above notwithstanding, I'm very pleased to see improvements being made to Stack Snippets.

Cheers for raising this - should now be sorted but anything else you spot please let me know!

Thanks!! And thanks for improving Stack Snippets.
